# Need help in understanding the example from Dummit & Foote text

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**This  is an example from Dummit & Foote text.**

> Let $D_{2n}=<r,s:r^n=s^2=1,s^{-1}rs=r^{-1}>$.Since [$r,s$]$=$$r^{-2}$,we have $\langle r^{-2}\rangle=\langle r^2\rangle \le D'_{2n}$.Furthermore,$\langle r^2\rangle \unlhd D_{2n}$ and the images of $r$ & $s$ in $D_{2n}/\langle r^2\rangle$ generate this quotient. They are commuting elements of order $\le 2 $,so the quotient is abelian and $D'_{2n} \le \langle r^2\rangle$.Thus, $D'_{2n}=\langle r^2\rangle$. Finally,note that if $n(=\vert r \vert$) is odd,$\langle r^2\rangle=\langle r\rangle$ whereas if $n$ is even,$\langle r^2\rangle$ is of index $2$ in $\langle r\rangle$.Hence,$D'_{2n}$ is of index $2$ or $4$ in $D_{2n}$ according to whether $n$ is odd or even,respectively.

NOTIONS WHICH I AM NOT GETTING

$\color{red}{(1)}$ How $\langle r^{-2}\rangle=\langle r^2\rangle $  ?

$\color{red}{(2)}$ How $\langle r^2\rangle \le D'_{2n}$?

$\color{red}{(3)}$ How does the images of $r$ and $s$ in $D_{2n}/\langle r^2\rangle$ generate this quotient?

$\color{red}{(4)}$ How if  $n(=\lvert r \rvert$) is odd,$\langle r^2\rangle=\langle r\rangle$ whereas if $n$ is even,$\langle r^2\rangle$ is of index $2$ in $\langle r\rangle$?

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted yesterday?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson:i'm extremely sorry,that i did'nt respond to your answer,actually my laptop  was having some technical problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $r^2$ is in the group generated by $r^{-2}$ (since it's $(r^{-2})^{-1}$), and $r^{-2}$ is in the group generated by $r^2$, so the two groups are equal.

(2) $D_{2n}'$ is, by definition, the group generated by the commutators; the calculation shows that $r^{-2}$ is a commutator, so the group it generates (which is the same as the group $r^2$ generates) is contained in $D_{2n}'$.

(3) $r$ and $s$ generate $D_{2n}$, so their images generate the quotient.

(4) That's how cyclic groups work. If you have a cyclic group of order $n=2s$, then $r^2$ generates the group $\{\,r^2,r^4,r^6,\dots,r^{2s}=1\,\}$, of index 2. If $n$ is odd, then you have to raise $r^2$ to the power $n$ to get the identity, so $r^2$ generates the whole group.

Comment: :will you please elaborate point (3).

Comment: Let $\phi:A\to B$ be a group homomorphism, let $x,y,z$ be in $A$, and suppose $z$ can be expressed in terms of $x$ and $y$. Then $\phi(z)$ can be expressed in terms of $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$. It follows that if $x,y$ generate $A$, then $\phi(x),\phi(y)$ generate the image of $A$ under $\phi$. A special case would be when $N$ is a normal subgroup of $A$, $B$ is $A/N$, and $\phi$ is the canonical homomorphism $\phi:A\to A/N$ given by $x\to xN$.